# Pros and cons of the Barbarians dlc?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

What are the good and bad points of the Barbarian hero? I'm gonna buy a hero at some point and i wanna know if he is worth it!

Comment: He has no towers, but can carry 2 squire weapons.  Instead he has "stances" which alter you player stats in different ways.  For more details, [see here](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Barbarian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages:

- His hero DPS, specifically burst damage, is arguably the highest in the game. Using heavy-hitting weapons along with hawk stance can do absurdly large amounts of damage, especially when boosted by the monk's abilities and/or a propellar cat.
- He has an ability to mitigate almost all incoming damage and not be affected by spider webbing. On top of that he has an ability to leech health from enemies. Both of these abilities can be used simultaneously.

Disadvantages:

- He has no defenses to call his own - all slots where defenses would normally be are replaced with stances, i.e. additional hero abilities.

This puts the barbarian in a unique situation where he is a valuable member to your team lineup in defeating bosses, but requires other heroes to summon defenses. If you're looking to buy one of the DLC heroes, I'd actually recommend purchasing the EV first. Her buff beams are a staple defense, especially in clearing content on Nightmare difficulty.